# Slim Framework - splitting code into multiple files other than index.php

Tags: php, slim

On the [documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/tutorial/first-app.html) for Slim Framework, it says

> In this example application, all the routes are in index.php but in
>   practice this can make for a rather long and unwieldy file! It’s fine
>   to refactor your application to put routes into a different file or
>   files, or just register a set of routes with callbacks that are
>   actually declared elsewhere.

It doesn't say how to actually do this though. My only thought is that you could split code into multiple PHP files and then use `include` or `require` in `index.php` to reference these.

I'm also not sure what it means by "register a set of routes with callbacks that are actually declared elsewhere"

Does anyone have any thoughts on this, since the application I'm wanting to build might have quite a few routes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're some thoughts on it in [Slim documentation](http://www.slimframework.com/2011/09/24/how-to-organize-a-large-slim-framework-application.html)

Instead of `require`'s you can use [composer autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload)

---

> "register a set of routes with callbacks that are actually declared elsewhere"

From [docs](http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-callbacks):

> Each routing method described above accepts a callback routine as its final argument. This argument can be any PHP callable...

So you can do:

```
$routeHandler = function ($request, $response) { echo 'My very cool handler'; };
$app->get('/my-very-cool-path', $routeHandler);
```

But usually people use classes instead of functions: 
http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#container-resolution

I think you almost get the basic idea right. I recommend reading chapter on routing a couple of times. It covers everything pretty good.

Happy coding and let me know if you need any other help!

Answer (score 9):

Being a micro-framework, Slim does not enforce any specific method. You can either find a ready-to-use structure ([Slim Skeleton Application](https://github.com/slimphp/Slim-Skeleton) comes to my mind) or write your own; unlike other frameworks, Slim does not try to protect you from PHP.

Route definitions can be something as simple as an array of strings:

```
<?php // routes.php
return [
    '/'        => ['Foo\\Home',    'index'],
    '/about'   => ['Foo\\Home',    'about'],
    '/contact' => ['Foo\\Contact', 'form' ],
];
```

... which you then load and process in your `index.php` entry point:

```
$routes = require('/path/to/routes.php');
foreach ($routes as list($path, $handler)) {
    $app->get($route, $handler);
}
```

And you can leverage the existing Composer set up to auto-load your classes by adding the appropriate directories to `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.3",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.19"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Foo\\": "./Foo/"}
    }
}
```

From here, it can get as complex as required: define routes in a YAML file, auto-load from defined classes, etc.

*(Code samples are shown for illustration purposes and might not even be valid.)*